# Can Ubuntu phones charge is the United States?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Can Ubuntu phones charge in the United States? I ask this because I know that in Europe they use a voltage different than the United States.

So, I was wondering if I will need a power converter when I get my Ubuntu phone.

Comment: Phones almost universally charge off of 5V ~1A. Your European charger takes 220/240V from the wall and drops the voltage to 5V. The only difference in the US is that it starts with 120V.

Comment: Most chargers these days take 110-240 volts.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer = You'll be fine.

The phone itself wont matter when it comes to charging. It's the adapter you use with it that will determine if it's compatible in your region. If you buy a Ubuntu phone or smart phone in Europe it will come with the plugs designed for the voltage in that region. If you buy a Ubuntu phone or smart phone from a vender from the United States it will come with the adapters required to charge the phone.

The phone doesn't care what country you charge it in. Just as long as it's getting power in was designed to receive.

Sometimes smart phones will come with multiple plug adapters for people that travel around the world.

Answer (score 1):

Voltage in Europe might be different than that of USA. So buy an adaptor which can work with your Europe cable and connect to wall socket in USA. Most of the electronic devices you don't need a voltage or frequency converter...just plain adapter will do.

For example - I am in USA(110 V AC, 60 Hz) and as and when i travel to India(220 V 50 Hz)- i carry [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007YLEQ58) which i purchased from amazon.com